# Jailbreak Application Development building and running the app

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak

I have been working on developing an app for iOS for a little while now.  The app runs fine within the sandbox, but I want to run the app from the `/Applications` directory.

My procedure for getting the app on the phone is:

1. Product -> Build For -> Testing
2. $ scp -r ~/Projects/KegCop/DerivedData/KegCop/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/KegCop.app
3. $ killall -HUP SpringBoard

After Spring Board restarts, I try launching the app but it just quits as soon as it starts.  I have AppSync for 5.x installed, and like I said if I leave the app in `/var/mobile/Applications/` it seems to work as expected.

Does anyone know why my app is quiting when I try to launch it from the `/Applications` directory?

Comment: how are you code-signing the app?  do you have the project's build settings setup the way you do for a normal (non-jailbreak) iOS app?

Comment: I have code signing turned off, but that isn't even issue until I figure out how to create a proper .deb file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Solved]

1) Make sure your release file is *Release* and not *Release.txt*

2) Make sure you generate a valid Packages file.

The *.deb* file I was generating was valid, but my *Packages* was foobar.

I used the following command *$ dpkg-scanpackages debs / > Packages* after changing into my local repo directory.

I then reuploaded everything, closed Cydia, and my app successfully installed \o/

cheers
-Chris